# Issue with application.properties file in java

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, properties

I am trying to fetch the database values from properties, so for the same reason I am using @PropertySource in spring, but it is throwing the FileNotFoundException

```
@Configuration
@EnableJpaRepositories(basePackages = {
        "com.manju.springdata.repository"
})
@EnableTransactionManagement
@EnableWebMvc
@ComponentScan(basePackages = "com.manju.springdata.*")
@PropertySource("classpath:/application.properties")
public class PersistenceContext {

    @Value("${db.driver}")
    private String dbDriver;

    @Value("${db.url}")
    private String dbURL;

    @Value("${db.username}")
    private String dbUserName;

    @Value("${db.password}")
    private String dbPassword;

    @Bean(destroyMethod = "close")
    DataSource dataSource(Environment env){
        BoneCPDataSource dataSource = new BoneCPDataSource();
        //dataSource.setDriverClass(env.getRequiredProperty("db.driver"));
        dataSource.setDriverClass(dbDriver);
        dataSource.setJdbcUrl(dbURL);
        dataSource.setUsername(dbUserName);
        dataSource.setPassword(dbPassword);
        return dataSource;
    }

    @Bean
    public static PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer propertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer() {
            return new PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer();
    }
    }
```

My project structure is as follows,

[image]

I am getting the following error,

```
Caused by: java.io.FileNotFoundException: class path resource [application.properties] cannot be opened because it does not exist
        at org.springframework.core.io.ClassPathResource.getInputStream(ClassPathResource.java:172) ~[spring-core-4.2.0.RELEASE.jar:4.2.0.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.core.io.support.EncodedResource.getInputStream(EncodedResource.java:153) ~[spring-core-4.2.0.RELEASE.jar:4.2.0.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.core.io.support.PropertiesLoaderUtils.fillProperties(PropertiesLoaderUtils.java:98) ~[spring-core-4.2.0.RELEASE.jar:4.2.0.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.core.io.support.PropertiesLoaderUtils.fillProperties(PropertiesLoaderUtils.java:72) ~[spring-core-4.2.0.RELEASE.jar:4.2.0.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.core.io.support.PropertiesLoaderUtils.loadProperties(PropertiesLoaderUtils.java:58) ~[spring-core-4.2.0.RELEASE.jar:4.2.0.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.core.io.support.ResourcePropertySource.<init>(ResourcePropertySource.java:84) ~[spring-core-4.2.0.RELEASE.jar:4.2.0.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassParser.processPropertySource(ConfigurationClassParser.java:360) ~[spring-context-4.2.0.RELEASE.jar:4.2.0.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassParser.doProcessConfigurationClass(ConfigurationClassParser.java:254) ~[spring-context-4.2.0.RELEASE.jar:4.2.0.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassParser.processConfigurationClass(ConfigurationClassParser.java:231) ~[spring-context-4.2.0.RELEASE.jar:4.2.0.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassParser.parse(ConfigurationClassParser.java:198) ~[spring-context-4.2.0.RELEASE.jar:4.2.0.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassParser.parse(ConfigurationClassParser.java:167) ~[spring-context-4.2.0.RELEASE.jar:4.2.0.RELEASE]
        ... 57 common frames omitted
```

How do I access my properties file values, what's wrong with my code? Any suggestions

Comment: Remove `/` from your `@PropertySource("classpath:/application.properties")`, try it.

Comment: Initially I tried that only. It is not working @Reno

Comment: Go into code which exception happened and debug it for real value of file path step by step.

Answer (score 2):

The problem is with your folder structure. The `resource` folder should be under `main`, not `java`. Look at [this](https://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-the-standard-directory-layout.html) for default structure of maven project.
Either move the resource folder or change value to `classpath:/resources/application.properties`.